# Strange compiler error with Swift protocol inheriting from Sliceable and adding a single property

Tags: swift

Consider the following code:

```
protocol CollectionStreamType: Sliceable {
    var position: Index { get set }
}

class Cell<T> {
    let contents: T
    init(_ contents: T) {
        self.contents = contents
    }
}

enum ParseResult<T, E> {
    case Matched([T])
    case NotMatched
    case Err(Cell<E>)
}

func then<S: CollectionStreamType, T, E where S.SubSlice == S>(parsers: [S -> ParseResult<T, E>])(stream: S) -> ParseResult<T, E> {
    let position = stream.position
    // ERROR IS HERE: Type '()' does not conform to protocol 'GeneratorType'. WTH?
    stream.position = position
    return .NotMatched
}
```

I'm writing a parser combinator library for Swift called Parsimonious. It works well, but I recently decided to replace my concrete collection type with a protocol, `CollectionStreamType`. When I did so, I started having problems.

This code is not directly from my parser combinator library, but it distills the problem to its essence and does cause the error I'm seeing, as follows:

> Type '()' does not conform to protocol 'GeneratorType'.

I'm baffled. Anyone have any insight on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most helpful of compiler errors, but I think it's because `stream` is not mutable, so you can't access its setter.  This compiles if you make `stream` `inout` or `var`, or if you make `CollectionStreamType` class-only.

Comment: I wasn't aware I could make a protocol class-only. How do I do that?

Comment: `protocol CollectionStreamType: class, Sliceable {`